# How to use existing Compute Engine for Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

How would you use an existing *Compute Engine* VM instance for a *Google Cloud Build* pipeline?

I know there's been a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763025/google-cloud-build-with-compute-engine) in the past, however, the suggested answer is not really what I want - creating and then destroying a Compute Engine with every build.

In settings, Cloud Build allows you to enable "service account permissions" for Compute Engine  (Compute Instance Admin (v1)), but I've found no information how to use that permission and service for running the build process with one of your predefined VM instances.

Or maybe I misunderstand the answer in the linked thread above and

```
COMMAND=sudo supervisorctl restart
```

actually restarts the existing VM supervisorctl? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't run Cloud Build on a specific instance (as you can do with other CI/CD tools). You have a managed service or private pool. But it's always managed, you never have access to the underlying VM. Anyway, what's your use case? Why do you need that access?

Comment: I was hoping to migrate a locally developed CI/CD pipeline to Google Cloud. However, since it includes ML training inside a docker environment, it would need a powerful VM to run the build and ideally come the possibility of a static IP.

Comment: Does it not better to start a powerful VM with Cloud Build, wait the end of the training and then stop the VM, deploy the model and do other things? The portage and the integration requires more step, but it's a better separation of concern and a better cost optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a Cloud Build build on a GCE instance. The most customizable option you would have is to run the build on a [private pool](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/private-pools-overview). But even in those cases it's always managed, you never have access to the underlying VM.

Another option would be to start a powerful GCE instance with Cloud Build via the GCE API, run your operations there and then stop the GCE instance.